# Guild Wars - How To Lower Ping / Change District?

Tags: technical-issues, guild-wars

I've never played the original GW - but I thought I'd give it a try.  When I connect and start playing, the game seems slow and unresponsive.  If I bring up the performance window I can see that my ping > 400ms.

Can anyone tell me if there are European verse US servers like there are in WoW?  I don't remember being asked, nor do I see a way to choose.

I've tried to Google it; but I'm having trouble avoiding results for 'Guild Wars 2'.  I was able to find information about 'Territorys' which seems like what I want; but I can't figure out how to set it's value.

My NCSoft account was created in the United States; perhaps there is no way to change it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original Guild Wars doesn't have servers like you might be used to in WoW. Instead, servers are split into "districts" that you can change at will. If you look in the upper left-hand corner of your screen (by default UI configuration), you'll see which district you're in at a particular time. If you're already in a European district and you're getting a high ping, try switching to an International district.

I haven't played in Euro districts much, myself, but I seem to recall some people complaining that they weren't as responsive as American districts. Since you can change for free, instantaneously, whenever you're in a town or outpost, might as well give all of them a shot and see which one works best for you.

[Relevant Wiki Article](http://wiki.guildwars.com/wiki/District)

Comment: That's absolutely perfect - I don't know how I missed it.  Ping is much better now.

Comment: @RobP. Well, considering that all other MMOs don't have cross server play and require server transfers and such for some inexplicable reason... not suprising you didn't look at that :p